# Two CombBoxes binding to object list inside an object list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a collection which binds to the Itemsource of a Combo box (Master combo box). Inside this is another collection which binds to another combox in a ItemControl which never populates. Please help

xaml

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding NodeNames}" DisplayMemberPath="name" 
                                          SelectedValue="{Binding ConditionalNodeId, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="id">

</ComboBox>
  </WrapPanel>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ConditionList}" AlternationCount="{Binding ConditionList.Count}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <WrapPanel>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding NodeMembershipFunction}">

            </ComboBox>
          </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Class code

```
public class ConditionsVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<ConditionsRuleModel> _ConditionList { get; private set; }
    public List<MembershipFunction> _NodeMembershipFunction { get; private set; }        

    public ConditionsVM()
    {
        _ConditionList = new ObservableCollection<ConditionsRuleModel>();
        _NodeMembershipFunction = new List<MembershipFunction>();

        List<MembershipFunction> m = new List<MembershipFunction>();
        foreach (MembershipFunction mf in ConditionNode.membershipFunctions)
        {
           m.Add(mf);
        }
        NodeMembershipFunction = m;
    }

    public List<MembershipFunction> NodeMembershipFunction
    {
        get
        {
            return _NodeMembershipFunction;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_NodeMembershipFunction != value)
            {
                _NodeMembershipFunction = value;


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please share full ViewModel.. It is not clear..

Comment: I think you should change the **List<MembershipFunction>** to **ObservableCollection<MembershipFunction>** and it should work.

Comment: @FloChanz I did but it does not help. I think the problem is xaml because I can debug the property and see that it has values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you assume that the second combobox has the same DataContext as the first one. That's not the case, the DataContext of the second combobox is a single element from ConditionList, i.e. a ConditionRuleModel.

So one way to solve it for the second combobox:

```
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.NodeMembershipFunction, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}, AncestorLevel=2}}"/>
```

I suspect that you need a AncestorLevel of 2 since the ComboBox itself is also an ItemsCOntrol. Not sure if the ancestor lookup starts at the element itself.